# Creating list of Occurences from list of names in Excel

Tags: excel, filtering, countif

I have a list of about 13,000 names.  I want to create an array/table that lists each name with the amount of times it shows up in the list.

For example, if I have:

```
Alex | Alex | Alex | Sam | Sam | Johnny
```

I want Excel to show me a table with:

```
Alex   | 3
Sam    | 2
Johnny | 1
```

I want Excel to automatically be able to find each of the different names in the list of names, without me having to type them in myself.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have edited my answer below, please have a look. Just follow it exactly and it will work. You can use the same formula but just have to change the ranges for you data tables.

Comment: I've edited your question, if is it's not OK you can roll it back ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the easiest way was to delete duplicates to get a list of just the distinct names in the column, copying that to a new sheet, restoring the duplicates and then using this formula on the new sheet and dragging down:

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet'!B1:B13000,A1)
```

Where Sheet/B1:B13000 references the range of all 13,000 names, and column A has distinct names (A1 as first in column).

Comment: With [absolute references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) `$B1:$B13000` or more simply `$B:$B` so the reference to the list doesn't shift when you fill the formula down?

Comment: @leerssej yes, that would be a better way.  In my case, the list is finite, however.

Comment: G - maybe separating array sources onto separate tabs will help?

Comment: G: maybe separating the array sections onto different tabs will help, too? Allow you to just copy the entire sheet of formulas in the tab and apply without modification to the other dataset, as well as ensuring you can't get the two separate regions entangled?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a pivot table. Make sure you have a heading on your list of names, such as "name". Create a pivot table with the name field in both the row label section and the value section. You will instantly have a count of each name.

Comment: newer editions of MS Excel, or conversely the surreptitiously powerful Google Sheets offer options to `count distinct` values in your pivot tables: that will make this task much easier.

Answer (score -2):

In another cell, type:

`=COUNTIF(` then drag to select all your data. The type `,` and type `"Alex")` and press enter.

so you are typing: `=COUNTIF(A1:A13000,"Alex")`

Do the same in the next cell for `Sam` and `Johnny`

**EDIT**

Since you want to automatically find the names (without having to type it in for each of the names), you will have to select the entire column with the names. Then, first make sure you have a header at the top of the columns like this:

```
Names
Alex
Sam
.
.
.
```

You need the "*Names*" header in the first row of the table.

Then, select this header. Then, in the ribbon, go to Data > Sort & Filter group and click "Advanced". Next, select "Copy to another location". And in the "Copy to:" range, click select any location in the same (or another worksheet). Finally click "**Unique Records only**" and click "OK". The list of names that are in the table will be copied. Now you can just replace the `"Alex"` in  the `COUNTIF` formula to `C2`. That cell is the location of where you have copied the names to. It is starting from the seconds row because the first row has the header.

You should type this `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$13000,C2)` formula in the cell `D2` so that the number of occurrences is displayed next to each name. Then drag the formula down next to each name. The "$" is to make the list of names an absolute range so it doesn't change when you drag the formula.

Here is a link to the Super User community for clarification if required:

https://superuser.com/questions/442653/ms-excel-how-to-count-occurrences-of-items-in-a-list

Comment: In my 13,000 rows I will have over 500 names.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: top of data row, then `Ctrl + Shift + DownArrow`, then type `, "Alex")`

Comment: @leerssej Yes, that works. But that is to select the entire column.

Comment: @DominicG. I have edited my answer for you. Please have a look now. it is relatively straightforward. The benefit of my method is that you will be able to also see each of the names automatically.

Comment: @Lakshya Goyal: Exactly right - `Ctrl + Shift + DownArrow` is to select the entire column between A1 and the farthest value down instead of having to mouse drag their selection area all the way down. btw: also preferable to hard entering the value as you later recommend.